# Closing a window.confirm in protractor with phantomJs

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I'm writing E2E tests with Protractor for my AngularJS app.

At some point the browser will encounter a `window.confirm`.

When using Chrome as the test browser, the following code works fine :

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

But on PhantomJS it raises the following error :

```
UnknownError: Invalid Command Method
==== async task ====
WebDriver.switchTo().alert()
    at tests/E2E/spec/search.spec.js:73:33
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at null.<anonymous> (tests/E2E/spec/search.spec.js:63:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (tests/E2E/spec/search.spec.js:6:1)
```

Any clue on how to handle it with PhantomJS ?

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no support yet for switchTo().alert() for PhantomJS/GhostDriver

I went for the following solution : mocking `window.confirm` as following :

```
beforeEach(function() {
    // bypassing PhantomJS 1.9.7/GhostDriver window.confirm (or alert) bug.
    // as WebDriver's switchTo().alert() is not implemented yet.
    browser.executeScript('window.confirm = function() {return true;}')
});
```

NB: I used jasmine for my Protractor tests, therefore I needed to put it in the beforeEach, else it would have no effect.

Comment: The Post seems quite older and now I am using PhantomJS 2.1.7. Any luck with that ?